# convert assembly file to hex dump in nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have this assembly file and I want to compile it to be in hex dump
how can I do that in nasm?

```
    L1: 
        mov si, 0ABCDh 
        cld
        lodsw;5566h
        std
        add ah, ah 
        add al, al 
        cmp ax, 0AACCh
        jne L1

    L2:
        mov si, 1711h
        cld
        lodsw;2222h 
        std
        mov dx, 5h
        mul dx
        cmp ax, 0AAAAh
        jne L2          
int 21h     
ret
```

I want it to be like this:

```
db 0BEh, 0CDh, 0ABh
db 0FCh, 0ADh, 0FDh
db 02h, 0E4h, 02h, 0C0h, 3Dh, 0CCh, 0AAh, 75h, 0F1h
db 0BEh, 11h, 17h, 0FCh, 0ADh, 0FDh
db 0BAh, 05h, 00h, 0F7h, 0E2h
db 3Dh, 0AAh, 0AAh, 75h, 0F0h
db 33h, 0D2h, 0BEh, 0FEh, 00h
db 21h, 0C3h
```

when I decompile it in IDA for example.
how can I do that using nasm?

Comment: You can get a listing including hex using `nasm -l/dev/stdout` (e.g. a codegolf answer on [Calculate the longest series of 1's in an integer's binary value](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143020)).  You could post-process that with `awk` or your favourite scripting language.